# WSO2 Data service - Erroring for Sybase stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, wso2, sybase, dataservice

I am  creating a WSO2 data service using a stored procedure in Sybase. I am getting errors whenever I assign values to local variables.

the stored procedure is as follows
...
Declare @user_id INT
select @user_id =333
....

The select statement above seems to be causing a problem and causing the below error

```
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Nested Exception:- javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.getMoreResults(int) has not been completed and should not be called. DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: testAmit Location: \testAmit.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Current Request Name: amitTestOps Current Params: {invId=22} Nested Exception:- com.sybase.jdbc3.utils.UnimplementedOperationException: The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.getMoreResults(int) has not been completed and should not be called.  </soapenv:Text>
```

If I comment the select statement , it works fine.

My data service looks like this

```
<data name="testAmit" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="sybaseAmit">
      <property name="driverClassName">com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver</property>
      <property ***db config deatils which I have omitted ***</property>
   </config>
   <query id="amitquery" useConfig="sybaseAmit">
      <sql>exec sp_createCorrespondence ?</sql>
      <result element="correspondences" rowName="correspondence">
         <element column="correspondence_id" name="correspondenceIdValue" xsdType="integer"/>
      </result>
      <param name="invId" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="amitTestOps">
      <call-query href="amitquery">
         <with-param name="invId" query-param="invId"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
(Using WSO EI version 6.1.1, jconn3.jar, sybase ASE 15.7)

Comment: Does your stored procedure contain `set nocount on`? If not, try adding it at the start of the procedure and see what happens. Also: please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Got this working! Needed to ensure the jconn3.jar version was newer and needed to add "set quoted_identifier off " before calling the stored procedure.